# AM PM functionality to be implemented

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application I want AM and PM functionality to be implemented. The user should not enter it by himself.I have a text box and the user should enter only numerical I also want to add time picker to it.

```
  %li
    %label{:for => "start_time"}Start_time<em>*</em>
    = f.text_field :start_time, :required => "required", :autofocus => true


  %li
    %label{:for => "end_time"}End_time<em>*</em>
    = f.text_field :end_time, :required => "required", :autofocus => true
```

Comment: are you sure that the above code is in ruby on rails? :-/ arent you missing some vital syntaxes?

Comment: I hope http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ will help...

Comment: @Sneha, Please rate my answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use `time_select` method & do something like this:

```
time_select("event", "start_time", :prompt => {:hour => 'Choose hour', :minute => 'Choose minute', :second => 'Choose seconds'})

time_select("event", "end_time", :prompt => {:hour => 'Choose hour', :minute => 'Choose minute', :second => 'Choose seconds'})
```

Hope it helps!